# Fetching user's facebook album list via IOS application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, image-uploading, photos

I'm writing an application for uploading the photos to the user's account from my application.
With following code i 'm succeeded of uploading the photo but still those photos doesn't directly uploads into the Album .
             Album thumbnails shows empty album whereas detail page comes withe following warning .
Would you like to add these photos to your album?
The photos below were uploaded from another application, you'll need to approve them.

I want to avoid following instruction . Do I need to set any permission parameter in my Facebook app count ?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: me also under the same situation. Did u get any solution?

Comment: Not the perfect solution but i did like this , First i tried to fetch the user's albums . If the album named as Timeline is present in the list took out the id and post the image in id/photos . If 'Timeline ' is not yet created for the user, i have posted in me/Photos that'll create the album named as our app name and post into that .